# Assert_failure src/proto_005_PsBabyM1/lib_protocol/contract_storage.ml:555:16

Tags: transactions, babylon

I don't know if this has been asked before, feel free to mark it as duplicate.

I'm simulating sending a transaction in BabylonNet with the exact amount of my balance. This is what I send:

```
{
    "operation": {
        "contents": [
            {
                "amount": "15072034",
                "destination": "tz1XSXBeWqdupm73qWAJkxJkxRzH16y77i1B",
                "source": "tz1Zccb24KHCe99goSnFpg4xh9JZNTHSNPTz",
                "storage_limit": "60000",
                "fee": "0000000",
                "kind": "transaction",
                "gas_limit": "800000",
                "counter": "252877"
            }
        ],
        "branch": "BM8(...)",
        "signature": "edsig(...)"
    },
    "chain_id": "Net(...)"
}
```

And I get a `500` error with this message:

```
[
    {
        "kind": "temporary",
        "id": "failure",
        "msg": "\"Assert_failure src/proto_005_PsBabyM1/lib_protocol/contract_storage.ml:555:16\""
    }
]
```

Checking out [the class in master branch](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_005_PsBabyM1/lib_protocol/contract_storage.ml) I'm assuming this error comes from the fact I'm trying to empty an account that delegated their tezos to a baker. Is this assumption correct? And if so, why does this block me from doing this transaction?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, you cannot empty a delegated implicit account. In 006 the assert is replaced with a [proper error message](https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/006_carthage.html#accounts).

Your options are to either leave at least 1 mutez in the account, or to remove the delegation and then empty the account.